# Javascript Callbacks with Object constructor

Tags: javascript, callback

Following is a function which creates and object and call the callback (not the exact code but something similar).

```
myObject = function(callback){

    var tmpThis = this;
    this.accounts = [];
    tmpThis.accounts[0] = 1;
    tmpThis.accounts[1] = 2;
    callback();
}

function caller(){
    var newMyObject = new myObject(function() {
        alert(newMyObject.accounts[1]);
    }); 
}
```

`newMyObject` is undefined inside the callback function. Is there a way I can access it. I read similar questions but none simply explains why.

I can fix it by passing back the created object in a second parameter to the callback function. But I think its a hack rather than the proper way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `this` to access the callback in the context of the newly create object, and `call` to invoke the callback.

```
myObject = function(callback){

    var tmpThis = this;
    this.accounts = [];
    tmpThis.accounts[0] = 1;
    tmpThis.accounts[1] = 2;
    callback.call(this);
}

function caller(){
    var newMyObject = new myObject(function() {
        alert(this.accounts[1]);
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This solved the asked problem. Now I have to apply it to my real application which is in Angular.:(

Answer (score 0):

`newMyObject` is not aware of `newMyObject` inside of the parameter which is passed into it. It will be undefined.

In other words, when `alert(newMyObject.accounts[1]);` is run, `newMyObject` as defined by `new myObject` wont exist yet.

`newMyObject` will be undefined when it is executed by the statement `callback();`, which runs the following code:

```
function() {
  alert(newMyObject.accounts[1]);
}
```

Your callback function is being passed into your myObject function. You can just `alert(accounts[1])` from within your myObject function.

The pattern you are attempting to use does not usually take a function callback. Usually you would pass in a object of options, which would serve to customize `myObject`.

It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
 function Application () {

    var self = this;

    myObject = function(callback){

        var tmpThis = this;
        this.accounts = [];
        tmpThis.accounts[0] = 1;
        tmpThis.accounts[1] = 2;
        callback();
    };

    function caller(){
        self.newMyObject = new myObject(function() {
            alert(self.newMyObject.accounts[1]);
        }); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The call hasn't finished yet. Set it to run in the next cycle:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/gWUD9/

```
myObject = function(callback){

    var tmpThis = this;
    tmpThis.accounts = [];
    tmpThis.accounts[0] = 1;
    tmpThis.accounts[1] = 2;
    setTimeout(callback,1);
}

    var newMyObject = new myObject(function() {
        alert(newMyObject.accounts[0]);
    });
```