# Javascript call function in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I had a strange problem in my Angular app so I asked some simple Javascript questions to make myself clear about the fundamentals (please see [Javascript Callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22164766/javascript-callbacks-i)). The solution worked fine for pure Javascript but when applied to my Angular app the problem still occurs.

I have defined a service which creates new instance of an object.

```
appModule.factory('myService', ["$rootScope", "$http", "DataCall", "$routeParams", "$log", function($rootScope, $http, DataCall, $routeParams, $log ) {

/////////////////////////// My- Object /////////////////////////////////////
MyObject= function(a, b, callback) { 
  var thisTemp = this;
  this.accounts = [];
  thisTemp.accounts[0] = 1;
  thisTemp.accounts[1] = 2;
  DataCall.get('xxx',function(data, status){                 
    callback.call(this);
    });
  } 
});
```

In my controller I create the new object and assign it to a scope variable

```
within controller....
$scope.pageInit = function () {
  $scope.currentObject = {};
  $scope.currentObject = new myService.MyObject('a', 'b', function(){

     alert(this.account[0]);
  });
```

This still doesn't work. Within the call back function 'this' refers to the 'window' rather than to currentObject.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Check my updated answer, that should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyObject= function(a, b, callback) { 
  var thisTemp = this;
  this.accounts = [];
  tmpThis.accounts[0] = 1;
  tmpThis.accounts[1] = 2;
  DataCall.get('xxx',function(data, status){
    // it is here 'this' become 'window'    
    callback.call(this);
    });
  } 
});
```

since you willing to read how javascript callback, I leave you to figure it out.

Comment: thanks @wayne. Just started reading the 'Bible of Javascript callbacks' ... I'll be done by tomorrow. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your MyObject you get hold of a reference to 'this' (which refers to the function MyObject) and you called it thisTemp. Since you got hold of that reference in a variable, you should use that variable instead of 'this' unless you want to reference another context.

```
appModule.factory('myService', ["$rootScope", "$http", "DataCall", "$routeParams", "$log", function($rootScope, $http, DataCall, $routeParams, $log ) {

  /////////////////////////// My- Object /////////////////////////////////////
  function MyObject(a, b, callback) { 
    var thisTemp = this;
    this.accounts = [];
    thisTemp.accounts[0] = 1;
    thisTemp.accounts[1] = 2;
    DataCall.get('xxx',function(data, status){                 
      callback.call(thisTemp);
    });
  }

  return {
    MyObject: MyObject
  }
}]);
```

within controller....

```
$scope.pageInit = function () {
  $scope.currentObject = {};
  $scope.currentObject = new myService.MyObject('a', 'b', function(data){

     alert(data.account[0]);
  });
```

Comment: @Wavy Unfortunately this doesn't work. Are you sure it work under AngularJS as well?

Comment: Can you post a plunkr of it, please?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to explicitly instantiate your service in the controller. Angular will already do this for you when it's needed.

So you could re-write your service to something like this.

```
appModule.factory('myService', ["$rootScope", "$http", "DataCall", "$routeParams", "$log", function($rootScope, $http, DataCall, $routeParams, $log ) {

  /////////////////////////// My- Object /////////////////////////////////////

    myService = {
      accounts : [],
      accounts[0] : 1,
      accounts[1] : 2,

      dataCall : function(a, b, callback) {
        callback.call(this);
      }
    }

    return myService;
});

within controller....
$scope.pageInit = function () {
  $scope.myService = myService;
  $scope.myService.currentObject = myService.dataCall('a', 'b', function(){

     alert($scope.myService.accounts[0]);
  });
```

Comment: We were going down the MVC path and trying to create objects which can be instantiated. But this makes sense too. If Angular service is true singleton there is no point of having a new function, right?

Comment: Exactly. Your way could work but I find Angular's use of singletons quite effective.